# AngularJS controller not being loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I have a simple `app.js` that is supposed to load a controller. The controller isn't being loaded though. Would appreciate some help.

Here is my `app.js`:

```js
/* globals APP, angular */
angular.module('templates-outlook', []);

angular.module(APP, [
     'templates-outlook',
     'ui.router'
])
.config[(
     '$stateProvider',
     function ($stateProvider) {
          console.log("Loaded app.js");

          $stateProvider
          .state('outlook', {
               url: '/extension',
               templateUrl: 'templates/outlook/outlook_main.html',
               controller: 'OutlookMainController'
          })

     }
])
```

Here is outlookmain.js . It's really simple.

```js
/* global angular, APP */


angular.module(APP).controller('OutlookMainController', [
     console.log('lion king'),
     function () {
          console.log('blah blah');
     }
]);
```

When I navigate to localhost/extension, I only see
lion king
Loaded app.js

Why am I not seeing "blah blah"?

Note: The reason I'm seeing lion king ( i think ) is that in the header i'm loading

```html
<script src="/load.php?f=outlook/app.js"></script>
<script src="/load.php?f=outlook/outlookmain.js"></script>
```

Comment: its because you are not invoking the function, blah blah logged inside the function so if you want invoke a function after its creation make the function IIFE see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript  but i have no idea what you are going to acheive with this!

Comment: Are you  getting eny error(s) in devtools console? (F12 in your browser)

Comment: I get IIFE, but I think it works differently in angular.

Comment: is it possible that you putt your code online, its easy to compile and check it

Answer (score 1):

Below is one of the example to declare the function.

```
 function nameOfFunction() {
      console.log('some text to print');
 }
```

For your requirement it should be like below.`

```
angular.module(APP).controller('OutlookMainController', [
     console.log('lion king');
     // Function declaration here
     function testFunction() {
          console.log('blah blah');
     }
     // Call the function here
     testFunction();
]);
```

`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem

Comment: yeah thats not the problem :(

Comment: @Asool Ummm, yes this is the problem (or part of the problem anyway).. A function does not run unless you call it, or define it as self-executing. You have done neither here.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller definition is incorrect:

```
angular.module(APP).controller('OutlookMainController', [
     console.log('lion king'),
     function () {
          console.log('blah blah');
     }
]);
```

When you change the formatting, it's easy to see that you are passing an array as the second argument.

```
angular.module(APP).controller('OutlookMainController', 
  [console.log('lion king'), function () { console.log('blah blah'); }]
);

angular.module(APP).controller('OutlookMainController', [console.log('lion king'), function() { console.log('blah blah'); }]
);
```

BUT, the array is supposed to contain injected services and providers, with the final element of the array being the function for your controller. Here, you are inserting a `console.log` statement. That does not make sense.

And, as you can see from this controller definition in Plunker, this code throws an error in the console: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/cHQjFsx3q0oHvkxC

> Error: [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service
>   name as string, got undefined

I think what you meant to do was this:

```
angular.module(APP).controller('OutlookMainController', [function() {
     console.log('lion king'),
     function () {
          console.log('blah blah');
     }
}]);
```

However, the anonymous function will still not be called unless you call it explicitly, take it out of the function, or define it as self-executing:

```
angular.module(APP).controller('OutlookMainController', [function() {
     console.log('lion king');

     console.log("blah blah blah");

     (function () {
          console.log('blah blah');
     })();

     function logBlah() {
          console.log('blah blah');
     }
     logBlah();
}]);
```

AngularJS does not change the basic principles of Javascript.